# Change VS option by using the Settings Store: finding the right CollectionPath?

Tags: c#, mef, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

I need to set the value of a Visual Studio option found in `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> JavaScript/TypeScript -> EsLint` but I can't seem to find the `CollectionPath` for this option.

`GetSubCollectionNames("Text Editor");` yield a number of results, while `GetSubCollectionNames("Text Editor\\JavaScript");` yield 0 results.

**TL;DR**
How would one go about finding the right `CollectionPath` for the option pictured in the image below?

[image]

This is what I'm using currently.

```
[ImportingConstructor]
internal VSOptions([Import] SVsServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var settingsManager = new ShellSettingsManager(serviceProvider);

    _writableSettingsStore = settingsManager.GetWritableSettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings)
        ?? throw new Exception(nameof(settingsManager));

    var textEditorSubCollections = _writableSettingsStore.GetSubCollectionNames("Text Editor");
    var javaScriptSubCollections = _writableSettingsStore.GetSubCollectionNames("Text Editor\\JavaScript");

    // TODO: set option value when we have the right CollectionPath
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WritabelSettingsStore class used to extend Visual Studio common settings in Visual Studio. You could use GetPropertyNames("Text Editor\JavaScript") to list all writabel settings for JavaScript, where you will find not all Properties under JavaScript sub collections are listed.

The [EsLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started) is not common Visual Studio Settings. It is third part tool for identifying and reporting on patterns found in ECMAScript/JavaScript code, with the goal of making code more consistent and avoiding bugs.

So we could not change it directly with WritableSettingsStore class. You need to know how the EsLint added in Visual Studio and then modify its configuration file for Visual Studio.